# Mouse is hovering only when you go to a particular point and not on the whole text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a **hyperlink** where in if I try to **hover over** it, only at a particular point of the **cursor** it will hover. But I want it to hover on the entire text. But I am not able to do it. Please help me. Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li ng-repeat="crumb in breadcrumbs" ng-class="{ active: $last }"><a
            ui-sref="{{ crumb.route }}" ng-if="!$last" translate>{{ crumb.displayName
                }}&nbsp;</a><span ng-show="$last" translate>{{ crumb.displayName
                }}</span></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

I want the first element in `<li>` tag to hover.

Comment: Any update on this please?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your a tag be present before the list?

```
<div class="container">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li ng-repeat="crumb in breadcrumbs" ng-class="{ active: $last }"><a
        ui-sref="{{ crumb.route }}" ng-if="!$last" translate>{{ crumb.displayName
            }}&nbsp;</a><span ng-show="$last" translate>{{ crumb.displayName
            }}</span></li>
</ol>
```

```
<div class="container">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li ng-repeat="crumb in breadcrumbs" ng-class="{ active: $last }"><a ui-sref="{{ crumb.route }}" ng-if="!$last" translate>{{ crumb.displayName
            }}&nbsp;<span ng-show="$last" translate>{{ crumb.displayName
            }}</span></a></li>
</ol>
```

Or, at least a little more spread out, such as after your span tag.

```
    <div class="container">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <a ui-sref="{{ crumb.route }}" ng-if="!$last" translate><li ng-repeat="crumb in breadcrumbs" ng-class="{ active: $last }">{{ crumb.displayName
            }}&nbsp;<span ng-show="$last" translate>{{ crumb.displayName
            }}</span></li></a>
</ol>
```

If you have an example of how this looks, this would probably make it much easier for me to answer this.

Comment: If I try the above code it is not working. Instead of actual name Home is getting displayed.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

li:first-child a:hover,li:first-child a:hover+span{background-color:gray}


</style>
</head>
```

Use the above code in header...